# Set ImageView at runtime

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, runtime

I'm developing a Java FX application and I want to show in a view at runtime a number of images according to an input number. I tried to do it in my controller class, but it shows no image.

```
private ImageView[] raccogliImg(){
    File file = new File("application/fotovoltaico1.jpg");
    for(int i=0; i<v.length; i++) {
        v[i] = new ImageView(new Image(file.toURI().toString()));
        anchor.getChildren().add(v[i]);
        anchor.requestLayout();
    }
    return v;
} 

@FXML
void onClick(ActionEvent event) {
    raccogliImg();
}
```

This is the controller class code

```
public class Controller {

public ImageView[] v = new ImageView[6];

@FXML
private ResourceBundle resources;

@FXML
private URL location;

@FXML
private Button button;


@FXML
private Pane pane;

private ImageView[] raccogliImg(){
    String file = "application/fotovoltaico1.jpg";
    Image img = new Image(file);
    for(int i=0; i<v.length; i++) {
        v[i] = new ImageView(img);
        pane.getChildren().add(v[i]);
        pane.requestLayout();
    }
    return v;
} 

@FXML
void onClick(ActionEvent event) {
    raccogliImg();  
 }



@FXML
void initialize() {
    assert button != null : "fx:id=\"button\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'prova.fxml'.";
}
```

}

Comment: Is there any exception logged in the output log?

Comment: No.The code is executed without errors

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't properly get the image.

```
String file = "application/fotovoltaico1.jpg";
Image image = new Image(file);
ImageView iv = new ImageView(image);
```

That will work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately I still can not view the image on the panel

Answer (score 0):

I just copy pasted your code and fixed to be compilable and runnable. Used VBox instead of Pane, so that images are not overlapped each over. It works without problem:

```
public class JavaFXApplication extends Application
{
    public ImageView[] v = new ImageView[6];
    private VBox pane = new VBox();

    @Override
    public void start( Stage stage )
    {
        raccogliImg();
        stage.setScene( new Scene( pane ) );
        stage.show();
    }

    private ImageView[] raccogliImg()
    {
        String file = "javafxapplication/applelogo.png";
        Image img = new Image( file );
        for ( int i = 0; i < v.length; i++ )
        {
            v[i] = new ImageView( img );
            pane.getChildren().add( v[i] );
            pane.requestLayout();
        }
        return v;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Application.launch( JavaFXApplication.class, args );
    }

}
```

So your problem is in different place.

Comment: In this case it works , but I wanted to combine this function to a method of a button on the controller class

Comment: `@FXML
void onClick(ActionEvent event) {
    raccogliImg();  
 }` should work.

Comment: I tried in this way , but when I click on the button does not compare no picture

Comment: @DavideSavasta then you need to provide a MVCE.

Comment: with the MVC can I dynamically change the graphical interface ?